# How to create dataframe of tuples out of dataframe of lists in pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Here is my dataframe:

```
my_df.show()

+----------+
|  features|
+----------+
| [0,'a']  |
| [1,'b']  |
| [0,'c']  |
| [1,'d']  |
| [2,'e']  |
| [0,'f']  |
+----------+
```

how to convert it into a dataframe of tuples (with single column 'features')?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
my_df.map(lambda x: (x[0],x[1]))
```

Comment: You might want to expand on your answer, perhaps show what the result is and explain why it is so.